# A book suggestion on algebraic number theory

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

I'm looking for a book on Algebraic Number Theory, which is somewhat in Analytic spirit.
In particular, I want to see the precise connection between

$$\delta_{f}(p)=\{a\pmod p : f(a) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}\}$$ and the L-series

$$\zeta_{K}(s)=\prod_{p: \mbox{prime ideal}}\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{Np}}\right)$$

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Comment: Check out this [math.overflow question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13282/good-algebraic-number-theory-books) and its answers!